# Why didn't Hermione try to get Slughorn's memory?

Tags: harry-potter

She kept hassling Harry about it, why didn't she try?

Comment: You should probably specify which particular book or film you're referring to.

Comment: This question has had a hell of a journey since it was asked.

Comment: How can this be opinion based when there is an answer based directly off the books?

Answer (score 37):

Dumbledore told Harry that he had to get it *personally*. Hermione trusts in his instinct that anyone else attempting to do it is doomed to failure and may well make it harder for Harry to get it in future.

> ‘I’m telling you, the stupid Prince isn’t going to be able to help you
> with this, Harry!’ said Hermione, more loudly. ‘There’s only one way
> to force someone to do what you want, and that’s the Imperius Curse,
> which is illegal –’
>
> ‘Yeah, I know that, thanks,’ said Harry, not looking up from the book.
> ‘That’s why I’m looking for something different. Dumbledore says
> Veritaserum won’t do it, but there might be something else, a potion
> or a spell …’
>
> ‘You’re going about it the wrong way,’ said Hermione. **‘Only you can
> get the memory, Dumbledore says. That must mean you can persuade
> Slughorn where other people can’t.** It’s not a question of slipping him
> a potion, anyone could do that –’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>

Comment: Turns out Harry was right, the solution was Liquid Luck and booze!

Comment: @JulienLopez - When *hasn't* that been the solution to a problem?

Comment: @JulienLopez I think that (in addition to Luck and alcohol) the story of Slughorn's favorite student's death told by her son himself also mattered.

Comment: @Valorum - Yup. Sometimes the most important lessons you learn in school aren't in any of the schoolbooks.